# Output of certain data to table the rest api php

Tags: php, json, get

I want to display certain data from dota 2 matches in the table. Namely, the match id, the start time and the name of the 2 teams and that only the first five. And I used the opendota api.

I could only make a get request, but it displays the last 100.

I could only make a get request, but it displays the last 100.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.opendota.com/api/proMatches';
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

}
$options= array(
    "match_id" => 3703866531,
    "duration" => 0,
    "start_time" => 0,
    "radiant_team_id"=> 0,
    "radiant_name" => "string",
    "dire_team_id"=> 0,
    "dire_name"=> "string",
    "leagueid"=> 0,
    "league_name"=> "string",
    "series_id"=> 0,
    "series_type"=> 0,
    "radiant_score"=> 0,
    "dire_score"=> 0,
    "radiant_win"=> true,
    "radiant"=> true
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.http_build_query($options));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);

?>
```

Comment: https://docs.opendota.com/#tag/pro-matches doesn't suggest any option to control how many results are returned, nor which ones (aside from limiting to those lower than a specific match ID. That is done using a parameter called `less_than_match_id`, but your code doesn't include one with that name in $options, so if your intent was to achieve that, you haven't done so simply because of not using the correct name!).

Comment: You should call ONLY the `proMatches` endpoint without additional parameters, as it returns the last 100 professional matches. Upon receiving the response, extract the specific data you're interested in – the match ID, start time, and the names of the Radiant and Dire teams. To display only the first five matches, limit your data processing loop to iterate through just the first five elements of the response array.  Try that.

Comment: Okay i try thanks!